# PCA memory error on GCP Compute Engine virtual machine

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, pca

I created a virtual machine on GCP Compute Engine with Windows Server 2016, with n1-highmem-4 (4 vCPUs, 2.2 GHz CPU, 26 GB memory) and 50GB of disk size at europe-west2 datacenter location.

I installed Pycharm in it and I run a simple PCA with python and scikit-learn on some images of resolution 529x940.
However, when I am running this on (only) 1000 rgb images then I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Sample/Main.py", line 130, in <module>
    pca.fit(data)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\decomposition\pca.py", line 329, in fit
    self._fit(X)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\decomposition\pca.py", line 370, in _fit
    copy=self.copy)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\Sample\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 444, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
MemoryError
```

My source code is the following:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from glob import glob
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn import neighbors
from sklearn import preprocessing
import shutil

data = []
i = 0
# Number of images
number = 800

# Load images from file
for filename in glob('Images/*.jpg'):
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    height, width = img.shape[:2]
    img = np.array(img)

    if height == 529 and width == 940 and i < number:
        i = i + 1
        # Transpose each individual rgb image to a row
        img = np.concatenate(img, axis=0)
        img = np.concatenate(img, axis=0)
        data.append(img)

# Normalisation
data = np.array(data)
Norm = preprocessing.Normalizer()
Norm.fit(data)
data = Norm.transform(data)

# PCA
pca = PCA(0.95)
pca.fit(data)
data = pca.transform(data)
print('Number of components:', pca.n_components_, '\n')
```

However, when I run the same python script on my laptop which only has a RAM of 8 GB along with a CPU of 2.7 GHz then I get no memory error for PCA when processing 800 images but it simply does not finish within a reasonable time (takes more than 8 hours)!

How is it possible that I get a memory error for 800 rgb images for PCA in GCP virtual machine which has very large RAM and I do not get it on my laptop which has pretty low RAM?